# PRODConfirmInvitationCode: "Could not fetch access token for Azure. Status code: 401, status message: Unauthorized"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

When doing deploy from Azure DevOps to azure subscription and getting error:

> Download secrets:
>
> PRODConfirmInvitationCode: "Could not fetch access token for Azure.
>   Status code: 401, status message: Unauthorized"
>   PRODSendInvitationCode: "Could not fetch access token for Azure.
>   Status code: 401, status message: Unauthorized"
>   PRODValidateInvitationCode: "Could not fetch access token for Azure.
>   Status code: 401, status message: Unauthorized"
>   PRODLehisoGraphEnabledClientId: "Could not fetch access token for
>   Azure. Status code: 401, status message: Unauthorized"
>   PRODLehisoGraphEnabledClientSecret: "Could not fetch access token for
>   Azure. Status code: 401, status message: Unauthorized"
>   PRODOticonGraphEnabledClientId: "Could not fetch access token for
>   Azure. Status code: 401, status message: Unauthorized"
>   PRODOticonGraphEnabledClientSecret: "Could not fetch access token for
>   Azure. Status code: 401, status message: Unauthorized"
>   PRODConfirmPasswordReset: "Could not fetch access token for Azure.
>   Status code: 401, status message: Unauthorized" PRODSendPasswordReset:
>   "Could not fetch access token for Azure. Status code: 401, status
>   message: Unauthorized" PRODValidatePasswordReset: "Could not fetch
>   access token for Azure. Status code: 401, status message:
>   Unauthorized"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source of error is that secret for service principal have expired so solution is to renew service principal key with can be done manual or automated.

[image]

[image]